# Android Studio Rendering Problems : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio version `2.2.3`. I make simple xml codes that contains just 50 buttons. But I have a rendering problem when I try to see preview. However, it normally runs in my smartphone devices. I changed API, Theme but they didn't work.
I download Android SDK : `Android 4.2, 4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 7.0, 7.1.1` 
Here is error message:-

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.reset(Paint_Delegate.java:1238)
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.<init>(Paint_Delegate.java:1179)
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nInit(Paint_Delegate.java:675)
    at android.graphics.Paint.nInit(Paint.java)
    at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:457)
    at android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.<init>(ColorDrawable.java:47)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:357)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:262)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:125)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try Build->Rebuild Project.

Comment: I tried Build->Rebuild Project & File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart. But they didn't work. Thank you for opinions